# Google Sheets invitation to edit on my Outlook email address

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, outlook.com

I have got an invitation to edit a Google document on my outlook.com email address, but every time I click on the link, I get the message “You need permission”. I am signed in to my Gmail account as well in the browser, and page says that at the bottom as well `(You are signed in as <email>@gmail.com)`.

How do I access the document without having to put a request for access for my Gmail ID as this is for an urgent official purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Does the individual who sent you the document have you listed as "having permission"? Google docs have various separate permission settings for who can view, edit, etc. The individual may not have specifically given you permission to either view or edit the document.

For example, one can give permission to view but not edit. Another setting may allow viewing and editing. And this can further be specified by "anyone with a link" or set to only certain individuals. If they have it set private, then they need to specifically give your Gmail/profile permission to access, view, or edit the document.

Comment: I assume he gave my email ID the permission to edit since the email I received was via Google Sheets.